# Upload an image using php and HTML to the cPanel 403 error

Tags: php, image, permissions, upload, cpanel

I am trying to upload an image to my host server but, but i am getting a `403 error` that i don't have permission to do so. i have tried raising permissions to my script and the containing site folder to 777 using chmod, but i still get the same `403 error`.

NB: my site is stored in the public_html folder
Below is the error i am getting
[image]

Here is the php code for uploading the image, its just a basic upload script which works well locally but when i host it throws a `403 error`.

```
    filename = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
        $target_dir = "/upload/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . $filename;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");
        $response = null;
        if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){    
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$filename);
        }
```

Someone had suggested that it might be because my php file upload options are off, just checked they are on.

[image]

Comment: change `"/upload/"` to `"upload/"`

Comment: i tried that already mate even tried to use the whole link from the root directory

Comment: Check your image size.

Comment: the image size is with my limit quite small actually B&W image of a fingerprint. @PiyushShukla

Comment: Check your target path existence using `var_dump(is_dir($target_dir))`.

Comment: Apache's MOD_SECURITY blocks form submissions that contains any HTML code. Try to upload the image without HTML code.